# Spring JPA Bi-Directional @ManyToOne doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

we have linked 2 entities with bi-directional @ManyToOne relation like this:

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo")
    private Set<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Bar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    private Foo foo;
}
```

When I create Foo entity and Bar entity, and try to set created Foo into Bar, change is not reflected on other side.

Here is code from my integration test:

```
Foo foo = fooRepository.save(Foo.builder()...build());

Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.setFoo(foo);
bar.set...();
barRepository.save(bar);

Foo updatedFoo = fooRepository.findById(foo.getId()).get();
List<Bar> bars = updatedFoo.getBars(); // this is null
```

I have no idea why bars from fetched foo is null. When I try fetch given Bar from repository I can see saved Foo on this side.

Comment: yes, with @Transactional

Answer (score 1):

have you try adding cascade to your mappings,

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo",cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Bar> bars;

@ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
private Foo foo;
```

and your code:

```
Foo foo = fooRepository.save(Foo.builder()...build());

Bar bar = new Bar(); 
bar.setFoo(foo);
bar.set...();
barRepository.save(bar);
```

barRepository.save(bar) will not persist the foo.

when you add cascade it will persist both the entities or you need to manually save the foo entity with fooRepository.

Comment: can you try by initializing the set i e, private Set<Bar> bars; = new HashSet<>();
and remove fetch.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

- JPA require you to set both sides of a relationship
- As long as you set the **owning side** `bar.setFoo()` which you did, the database will be updated with the relationship changes. **So your database is correct**
- The **non-owning side** `foo` will only reflect what is in the database if you manually set it, or **you force it to be refreshed or reloaded eg `entityManager.refresh(foo)`**

**Notes**

- In a transactional session, every call to repository does not translate to database call. Since hibernate all ready has `foo` as a `managed` entity in line1,
  when you call, `fooRepository.findById(foo.getId()).get();` JPA does not issue a select statement. **If you search about `Transactional write-behind` and `Repeatable Read`, you can find out about this more**
- `Foo foo = fooRepository.save(Foo.builder()...build());` - `foo` becomes managed entity, due to `Repeatable read` guarantee, JPA will return the same `foo` for all subsequent retrievals of `foo`.
- It does not even go to database if you call `fooRepository.findById(fooId)` after the save.
- `barRepository.save(bar);` - `bar` also becomes managed
- Both `foo` and `bar` are managed entities, but foo says I don't have any `bar`s and bar says I know a `foo` as you didn't set `foo.getbars().add(bar)`. This is incorrect **in memory** as you have to explicitly set both side of relationships.
- If you complete the current `transactional method` without adding the bar to foo, and then if you call `fooRepository.findById(fooId)` in **another** transactional, it will show you it get foo and bars.

**More references**

- [why-do-i-need-to-set-the-entities-both-ways-in-jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534104/why-do-i-need-to-set-the-entities-both-ways-in-jpa)
- [do-i-have-to-set-both-sides-for-a-bidirectional-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754783/do-i-have-to-set-both-sides-for-a-bidirectional-relationship)